# BatchNormalization layers in Tensorflow 2.4.1 give constant validation accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I was building a simple CNN for a binary image classification task and found something confusing regarding the use of the `BatchNormalization` layer in Tensorflow. There are 320 images in the training set with evenly divided negative and positive cases. There are 80 images in the validation set with evenly divided negative and positive cases. I set the `batch_size` for both training and validation set to 32.

Here is the architecture of my original model.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
        
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(256, 256, 3]),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation=“relu”),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(64, activation=“relu”),
    Dense(1, activation=“sigmoid”)
])
```

Both training and validation accuracies increased from somewhere between 0.5 and 0.6 and eventually converged somewhere between 0.95, which is good. However, with everything else unchanged, if I introduced `BatchNormalization` layers between `Conv2D` layers like the following:

```
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(256, 256, 3]),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=“same”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    ReLU(),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=“same”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    ReLU(),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    ReLU(),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    ReLU(),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation=“relu”),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(64, activation=“relu”),
    Dense(1, activation=“sigmoid”)
])
```

The training accuracy still behaved the same way as before but validation accuracy remained constant at 0.5. I also tried several other implementations of `BatchNormalization` layers and had the same observation.

```
model = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(256, 256, 3]),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding=“same”, activation=“relu”),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation=“relu”),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(64, activation=“relu”),
    Dense(1, activation=“sigmoid”)
])
```

I am rather new with deep learning and from what I have read recently on different tutorials about `BatchNormalization`, it should usually (though not always) be a performance booster. However, from what I have observed, `BatchNormalization` was ruining my validation performance. There are people online saying that there are bugs in Keras’s implementation of `BatchNormalization`. I had tried to reduce the layers of `BatchNormalization` and found that with even a single layer of `BatchNormalization` introduced, the validation accuracy will be constant at 0.5. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Is your main task binary classification or multi-class? If binary then changes last layer activation to 'sigmoid`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the typo, it should be `sigmoid`. I was typing the code from iPad rather than copying and pasting it from my desktop. In my actual running of the code, it is `sigmoid`. I have updated my question to reflect the change.

Comment: Can you share some reproducible code? If this is general, then you can reproduce this with the mnist or cifat10 dataset.

Comment: The default value for `momentum` in `BatchNormalization` is `0.99` which is quite high, try using `0.90` instead like so `BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)`.

Comment: @ M.Innat I was using Fundus images and haven’t tested it on mnist dataset.  Thanks for reminding me. I’ll try to give a reproducible code snippet soon.

Comment: I tested with your `Conv - BN - Conv - BN ....` with mnist and unable to reproduce abnormal stuff. I think this is more about the task-specific problem rather than BN itself.

Comment: Check the document for details of [BN](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/) on inference time.

Comment: @yudhieshThank you for your suggestion. It somewhat improved the situation. The val_accuracy remain constant at 0.5 in the first two epochs and started taking off later. Here is what I observed in val_acc in each epochs 0.5, 0.5, 0.5750, 0.9375,  0.8125, 0.9625, 0.9125, 0.9125, 0.9625, 0.9750, 0.9750, 0.9750…… 0.9750 till the very end. I was in fact expecting a more smoothing change in val_acc. It’s possible that in this trial, I removed all the dropout layers. But I think this is the way to go.

Comment: I used Pytorch BatchNorm2D’s default momentum(0.1), episilon(1e-5) and achieved 0.95 at the first epoch.